# Toggle the appended element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know it is pretty simple but I can't get it worked for some random reason, Hope to get some clue on this.

Here is my problem,

I need to append html element on page load and when the other element is clicked I need to change the place of the appended element based on the class name.

Currently I am able to append the div on page load, but the problem is in when switching the place of appended element.

Here is what I have written

```
$(".panel_blue").append($("<div class='red' />"));

$('.red').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.panel_green').removeClass('panel_green').addClass('panel_blue');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('panel_blue').addClass('panel_green');
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/xobiquxi/2/)**

Comment: your problem is `$('.red').click(...)` is assigned only to the currently existing elements. `$(stable_parent_element).on('click','.red')` is the proper assigment for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? Append the red box to the blue class on click.

```
$('.red').on('click',function () {    
    $('.panel_green').removeClass('panel_green').addClass('panel_blue');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('panel_blue').addClass('panel_green');
    $(this).appendTo('.panel_blue');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g24EL/3/)

Comment: Nice but there is problem when there are multiple panel. Please check this demo of yours edited http://jsfiddle.net/g24EL/4/

Comment: @Sowmya Do you want to add it to the first previous panel?

Comment: You did not mention that in your question. Can't you use an ID instead of a class?

Comment: @Anton There will be many panel_green divs and blu one is selected one.

Comment: Exactly this is it. Thnaks Man

Comment: Oops Sorry.... One last question I said it in opposite way. There willbe multiple blue box with red inside it and there will be only one green panel. Please check the problm in that case here http://jsfiddle.net/g24EL/6/

Comment: @Sowmya I'll reply with an answer in a few min. Got to do something first.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(this).hide();` with `$(this).detach().appendTo('.panel_green');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method. So your complete code will be

```
$('.red').click(function(){
    $('.panel_green').removeClass('panel_green').addClass('panel_blue');           
    $(this).parent().removeClass('panel_blue').addClass('panel_green');
    $(".panel_blue").append($(this).clone());
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBBq2/)

Comment: Why a new answer? Anton's answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: he has not used clone method @MrUpsidown

Comment: Maybe because you don't need to?

Comment: Sure it works. But I always wonder why such questions need so many different answers when a good one is proposed. Anyway...

Answer (score 0):

in this i am removing red box after changing class of divs. it's working as you wanted.

```
$(".panel_blue").append($("<div class='red' />"));
 $(document).off("click", ".red").on("click", ".red", function (e) {  $('.panel_green').removeClass('panel_green').addClass('panel_blue');
    $(this).parent().removeClass('panel_blue').addClass('panel_green');
    $(this).remove();
    $(".panel_blue").append($("<div class='red' />"));
});
```

see fiddle link    http://jsfiddle.net/3LZ2H/